# How to fix a lag when scrolling over a line chart that has already been drawn in scichart android

Tags: android, scroll, scichart

I have a line chart that has already been drawn and synced with a sound.
when we play sound, chart begin to scroll horizontally.
but problem is lagging when scrolling chart.
Is there a way to fix this problem?

```
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    forceRunInPauseMode = false;

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
        currentTime = (int) exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        binding.tvCurrentDuration.setText(MiliToTimeConverter.milliToTime(currentTime));
    });

    int currentRange = currentTime * 2;


    if (!isDraw) {
        DoubleValues xValues = new DoubleValues(Arrays.copyOfRange(xDoubleArray, 0, xDoubleArray.length - 1));
        DoubleValues yValues = new DoubleValues(Arrays.copyOfRange(yDoubleArray, 0, yDoubleArray.length - 1));
        DoubleSeries doubleSeries = new DoubleSeries(xValues, yValues);
        lineData.append(doubleSeries.getxValues(), doubleSeries.getyValues());
        isDraw = true;
    }
    xVisibleRange.setMinMax(currentRange - visibleInterval / 2, currentRange + visibleInterval / 2);
}};


private void updateChart() {
schedule = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
    if (!isPlaying && !forceRunInPauseMode)
        return;
    UpdateSuspender.using(binding.sciChart, mRunnable);
}, 0, TIME_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);}


private void pause() {
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
binding.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
if (schedule != null)
    schedule.cancel(false);}
```

Comment: Did you try to profile your application using Android Studio profiler? What does it show?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which I see that can be improved - creation of double arrays which are GC after using in run(). This can cause signifant degradation of performance if size of array is large or/and it's recreated many times.

I would suggest to cache DoubleValues outside run() call and reuse them.

```
 private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    private final DoubleValues xValues = new DoubleValues();
    private final DoubleValues yValues = new DoubleValues();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        forceRunInPauseMode = false;

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
            currentTime = (int) exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            binding.tvCurrentDuration.setText(MiliToTimeConverter.milliToTime(currentTime));
        });

        int currentRange = currentTime * 2;


        if (!isDraw) {
            xValues.setSize(xDoubleArray.length);
            yValues.setSize(yDoubleArray.length);

            System.arraycopy(xDoubleArray, 0, xValues.getItemsArray(), 0, xDoubleArray.length);
            System.arraycopy(yDoubleArray, 0, yValues.getItemsArray(), 0, yDoubleArray.length);

            lineData.append(xValues, yValues);
            isDraw = true;
        }
        xVisibleRange.setMinMax(currentRange - visibleInterval / 2, currentRange + visibleInterval / 2);
    }};
```